# IntelliJ IDEA минимальная версия android

Tags: java, android-sdk

Как в IntelliJ IDEA выбрать минимальную версию андроида в проекте?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как поменять минимальную для проекта версию Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709309/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%b2-android-studio)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как поменять минимальную для проекта версию Андроид?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709309/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4)

Answer (score 3):

В файле `build.gradle` укажите значение `minSdkVersion` нужную вам версию.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, увидел.