# Как поменять минимальную для проекта версию Андроид?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Можно ли поменять минимальную версию Андроид, на котором будет работать проект? (Эти настройки задаются при создании проекта)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `gradle.build` на уровне `app`

```
minSdkVersion 17
```

Там где 17 укажите минимум который будет поддерживаться

Answer (score -1):

for example:

- a project name is 'myProj';
- minimum SDK must be 4.1.

ANDROID STUDIO, in 'Android', under 'app' fold in 'Gradle Scripts / build.gradle (Module:myProj.app)':

android {...
compileSdk 32
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.myProj"
minSdk 16
targetSdk 32
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"...
}...
}

If you need another minimum SDK you should create a new project blank in your minimum SDK, look at the same snipet and change 'build.gradle (Module:myProj.app)'.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык