# Как поменять версию андроид на 4.4 в android studio?

Tags: android-studio

[как поменять минимальную для проекта версию андроид в Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709309/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%b2-android-studio)

видел эту статью но здесь меняют на минимальную, а мне нужно именно поменять на 4.4, и какие ошибки нужно ожидать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо установить свойство Gradle `compileSdkVersion=19` - это соответствует начальной версии Android Kitkat 4.4

`compileSdkVersion` - задает версию компилятора, который будет использоваться для сборки, по сути это означает, что вы не сможете использовать версии API > 19

Дополнительно надо еще устанавливать `buildToolsVersion=19.x` - это версии aapt/dx/zipalign и проч. утилит, которые будут использоваться. Обычно надо пользоваться самой последней версией, в вашем случае это `buildToolsVersion=19.1.0` ([описание релизов здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools)

Comment: а вот как можно узнать какой версии андроид, какое минимальное sdk прописывать? просто для себя

Comment: Опять двадцать пять - версия андроида и `minSdk` почти не связаны с собой. Можно собрать на Android 10 c `minSdk` для Android 4, можно собрать на Android 4 c `minSdk` для Android 4 :)

Comment: аа спасибо, просто учусь

Answer (score -1):

В указанной вами статье меняется минимальная версия системы андроид, на которой будет работать ваше приложение. Если вы хотите, чтобы приложение запускалось именно начиная с версии 4.4., ставьте 
В gradle.build minSdkVersion 20.